# using both html and jsp as view in spring mvc

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc

can we use jsp and html both in our spring mvc project if yes then how the mapping will be done in servlet-context.xml so that the control from the controller goes according to our requirement i.e. to html or jsp.

Answer (score 1):

Configure multiple view resolvers based on priority, like below..

```
<bean id="viewResolverjsp" class="example.SmartInternalResourceViewResolver" 
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" p:order="1"/>

<bean id="viewResolverhtml" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/html/" p:suffix=".html" p:order="2"/>
```

Comment: but if i am not wrong InternalResourceViewResolver  passes controls only to jsp and servlet, so it will give an error in calling.

Comment: we can use this for html:
<bean id="staticViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/static/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
</bean>

Comment: ThymeleafViewResolver it's only for view html and xhtml..it is also open source. You can still continue to use the same View resolver but set the suffix to empty.But according my knowledge can use for html InternalResourceViewResolver. I am not sure check with spring docs..